# Capture Ng-click event from button inside the texteditor in text-angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, rich-text-editor, textangular

**Use-case** : User clicks on a button inside text angular textarea and applications angular function to be invoked
**Changes made** :  We had added ng-click, onclick events in `textAngular-sanitize.js` refer below screenshot

[image]

and added button in svgIcons variable

[image]

So that a button should get displayed and ng-click, onclick not to be stripped out.  Button with the ng-click is rendered successfully but onclick of the button we need to call a angular function in our application.

**Issues faced**: The ng-click is not calling any function and we don't know under the hood how to make it work.

[Pluker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZYtuTD8pZn93FxsC?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1&preview).

Unfortunately I am not able to make the plunker work but the code change is there what we are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

I found that there is a event provided in text-angular for any of the tag type like the button I was asking in the question is actually a anchor tag.So I captured the anchor tag click by registering the event in taRegisterTool like below

```
taRegisterTool('yourWish', {

iconclass: "fa fa-xxxxx",

onElementSelect: {
  element: 'a',
  action: function(event, $element, editorScope){
    alert('Got the anchor tag selection event');       
}
}
```

});